# get envronment variables in python without expanding it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using os module to get environment variable . My Variable contains `${NAME}` in it. So when I try to getting value using  `os.environ.get(VALUE1)` , the value gets expanded and I am not getting the desired value.

For example i did :

```
export VALUE1="www.xyz.new${NAME}.com"
```

then when i try to get this value in my code

```
os.environ.get('VALUE1')
```

I get `www.xyz.new.com`  when  should get `www.xyz.new${NAME}.com`

how can i avoid this expansion and get the value as it is defined in env variable

Comment: The variable was expanded when you assigned it.

Comment: `${NAME}` *isn't* part of the value; the shell expanded it before assigning the resulting string to `VALUE1`. You probably wanted `export VALUE1='www.xyz.new${NAME}.com'` (single quotes)

Comment: Also you shouldn't have spaces in the variable assignment.

Comment: yes i have edited that part . it is assigned without spaces. this value is coming from userdata in the instance . i dont have an option to export with single quotes .